# Groovy expression in JasperReports: using Java's enum in comparison

Tags: groovy, jasper-reports

Is it possible to compare two *Java* objects using *Groovy* syntax inside a report if one of them is Enum?

Right now my report fails during execution with `more Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: RequestServiceState`

Expression:

```
($P{service}.state.id == RequestState.Offer.id ? "true" : "false")
```

where RequestState is:

```
public enum RequestState {
    New(1), InProcess(2), Pending(3), Offer(4), Order(5), Done(6);

    private Integer value;

    private RequestState(final Integer value) {  
        this.value = value;  
    }  

    public Integer getId() {  
        return this.value;  
    }  

    public static RequestState getValue(final Integer value) throws EnumValueNotFoundException {  
        switch (value) {  
            case 1:  
                return New;  
            case 2:  
                return InProcess;
            case 3:  
                return Pending;
            case 4:  
                return Offer;
            case 5:  
                return Order;
            case 6:  
                return Done;
            default:
                throw new EnumValueNotFoundException(value);
        }  
    }
}
```

All imports are made.

Comment: You should post the expression

Comment: `id` - Is it primitive type (int?)?

Comment: And what type of `$P{service}`? :)

Comment: It is some object that has state property of type RequestService

Comment: Can you post the `$P{service}` definition (from the *jrxml* file)?

Comment: `<parameter name="service" class="java.lang.Object"/>`

Comment: Have you tried the full package name to the enum, ie: `($P{service}.state.id == org.whatever.RequestState.Offer.id ? "true" : "false")`

Comment: 1. $P{service} must have concret class (not java.lang.Object)
2. This class must contain method getState()   AFAIK jasper work with private members using getters, but not name of variables.

Try to make getter method and use it instead direct memeber of class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *enum type* in expressions.

I agree with **tim_yates** - I think that you forgot to add import in *jrxml* file for *RequestState* and this is why you catch this exception.

Another problem was mentioned by **sanBez** - you should use *Bean* in right way. See details below.

#### The sample of using enum.

The *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test_enum" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="5950245d-5a85-43a8-a4f6-9e11b44e62d1">
    <import value="packagename.*"/>
    <parameter name="service" class="RequestBean" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="b5084124-1a2c-4bb9-ad93-503aa8474c12" x="122" y="28" width="336" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($P{service}.state.id == RequestState.Offer.id ? "true" : "false")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The *RequestState enum* code is:

```
package packagename;

public enum RequestState {

    New(1), InProcess(2), Pending(3), Offer(4), Order(5), Done(6);

    private Integer value;

    private RequestState(final Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public static RequestState getValue(final Integer value) throws IllegalStateException {
        switch (value) {
            case 1:
                return New;
            case 2:
                return InProcess;
            case 3:
                return Pending;
            case 4:
                return Offer;
            case 5:
                return Order;
            case 6:
                return Done;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }
}
```

The Beans classes are here. The *RequestBean* class:

```
package packagename;

public class RequestBean {

    private StateBean state;

    public RequestBean(StateBean state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public StateBean getState() {
        return state;
    }
}
```

The *StateBean* class:

```
package packagename;

public class StateBean {

    private Integer id;

    public StateBean(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

And the test code is:

```
public static void testReport(String reportSource, String outputFileName) throws JRException {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    params.put("service", new RequestBean(new StateBean(4)));

    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, new JREmptyDataSource());

    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, outputFileName);
}
```

The result will be (generated *pdf* file):

[image]

***Notes***:

1. Don't forget to add all classes to *classpath*
2. Don't forget to add imports in *jrxml* file (or use the full name for classes)
3. Don't forget to make fields of *Java Bean* visible for *jvm*. See details about using of [JavaBean Data Sources](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html#javabeandatasources).